# BeutifulSoup extracting from td, span and style

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<td><span data-tooltip="some text" class="tooltip button is-success is-small" style="cursor: default;">
23 - 1 - 13 (<span class="is-danger" style="font-weight: 700;">1.77</span>)
```

I'm looking for those numbers 23 - 1 - 13. How can I extract them? I'm using BeautifulSoup in Python.

Comment: and what is your code what you try?

Comment: I tried soup.find_all('td', class_="tooltip button is-success is-small") but it shows nothing

Comment: edit your question with code and trouble description, read some other question with tag `beautifulsoup` it can help you to create good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do the find on the `span` and not the `td` as it is that element that contains the class you are searching for:

```
soup.find_all('span', class_="tooltip button is-success is-small")
```

Also you could use `soup.span.text` to locate the text in the `span` tag. Then some standard Python to split it up and convert it into numbers. If there are multiple elements, this could be done as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<td><span data-tooltip="some text" class="tooltip button is-success is-small" style="cursor: default;">23 - 1 - 13 (<span class="is-danger"style="font-weight: 700;">1.77</span>)</td>
<td><span data-tooltip="some text" class="tooltip button is-success is-small" style="cursor: default;">23 - 1 - 13 (<span class="is-danger"style="font-weight: 700;">1.77</span>)</td>
<td><span data-tooltip="some text" class="tooltip button is-success is-small" style="cursor: default;">23 - 1 - 13 (<span class="is-danger"style="font-weight: 700;">1.77</span>)</td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for span in soup.find_all('span', class_='tooltip button is-success is-small'):
    numbers = [int(v) for v in span.text.strip().split(' ')[:-1] if v != '-']
    print(numbers)
```

This would give you the three numbers in a list as follows:

```
[23, 1, 13]    
[23, 1, 13]    
[23, 1, 13]
```

Comment: It works fine where there's only one element but I have around 20 results like in the post. I'm trying to receive all the numbers. I tried: 
results = soup.find_all('span', class_="tooltip button is-success is-small")
for elements in results:
    numbers = [int(v) for v in elements.span.text.strip().split(' ')[:-1] if v != '-']

but I receive 0 results.

Comment: You need to edit your question to provide a more realistic example. I have updated the script to show one possible way to do it.